# Regex to find <h1>Kalani Doe</h1> but not <h1>Kalani Do | Profile</h1>

Tags: regex

I need to find first names and last names inside H1 element such as,

```
<h1>Kalani Doe</h1>
```

But not one that has the word "Profile" in it, such as,

```
<h1>Kalani Doe | Profile</h1>
```

I know I need to use `?!` but I can't get around to understand how to combine positive and negative.

I tried this,

```
(<h1>(.+?)<\/h1>)(?!<h1>(.+?)Profile<\/h1>)
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: what was the regex you tried?

Comment: is this `<h1>Kalani Doe<\/h1>` won't work?

Comment: `<h1>\w+ \w+<\/h1>`

Comment: Sorry @AvinashRaj I clarified what I meant in my post. I'm looking for first names and last names without the word "Profile" inside the H1 tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use negative Lookbehind `(?<!chars)`

```js
const str = `<h1>Kalani Doe</h1>
<h1>Kalani Doe | Profile</h1>
<h1>John  Doe</h1>`;

let m = str.match(/<h1>.*(?<!Profile)<\/h1>/gm)
console.log(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the availability to use a Dom parser, you could get all the h1 elements, and check if the string does not contain Profile.

As there is only a regex tag, and assuming there are no other angle brackets inside, you can use negated character class instead of `.+?` as the dot can match any character.

If Profile should not be right before the closing tag:

```
<h1>[^<]*<(?<!\bProfile<)\/h1>
```

- `<h1>` Match literally
- `[^<]*<` Match any char except `<` and then match `<`
- `(?<!\bProfile<)` Assert not Profile< to the left
- `\/h1>` Match `/h1>` (Note that depending on the pattern delimiter, the `/` does not need escaping by itself)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ugz13B/1)

If there should be no Profile at all:

```
<h1>(?![^<]*\bProfile\b)[^<]*<\/h1>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IycpLN/1)